# C# Matrix output by MessageBox

Tags: c#

I want to know how to use messagebox to show the inverse matrix that I get from calculating.

```
OOPTools_Math.Matrix Inver = new OOPTools_Math.Matrix(5, 5);

Inver = A.Invert(A);
```

My idea is to construct the new matrix and input the information from `Inver = A.Invert(A)`, then use `Messagebox.Show()`.

============================================

I modified a little bit

```
OOPTools_Math.Matrix Inver = new OOPTools_Math.Matrix(5, 5);

Inver = A.Invert(A) ;

string i = Inver.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(i);
```

=============================================================

Here is what I have done

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OOPTools_Math.Matrix A = new OOPTools_Math.Matrix(5, 5);

    A.Values[0, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    A.Values[0, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    A.Values[0, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
    A.Values[0, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    A.Values[0, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
    A.Values[1, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
    A.Values[1, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
    A.Values[1, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
    A.Values[1, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text);
    A.Values[1, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);
    A.Values[2, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text);
    A.Values[2, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text);
    A.Values[2, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text);
    A.Values[2, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text);
    A.Values[2, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text);
    A.Values[3, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text);
    A.Values[3, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox17.Text);
    A.Values[3, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text);
    A.Values[3, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox19.Text);
    A.Values[3, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox20.Text);
    A.Values[4, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox21.Text);
    A.Values[4, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox22.Text);
    A.Values[4, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox23.Text);
    A.Values[4, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox24.Text);
    A.Values[4, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox25.Text);

    OOPTools_Math.Matrix Inver = new OOPTools_Math.Matrix(5, 5);

    Inver = A.Invert(A);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        double i = Inver.ToString();

        return base.ToString();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(i);
}
```

Comment: If `Inver` is the value you want to show in the Messagebox, just use `Messagebox.Show(Inver)`

Comment: I tried but it can not transfer to string.

Comment: @TzuYuTseng you have to override ToString method.Check out my answer

Comment: What are you specifically having trouble with? How would you like the matrix data formatted? What is preventing you from writing the code to format it in the way you want? The given answer (so far) is correct in that you could override the `ToString()` method, but it's not clear that's going to help you figure out what to actually put in that method override.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 
I want to use messagebox to show my result which is 5 by 5 matrix. 
I try to use the override method but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question and comments than "it doesn't work". Include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I add it to the above question. If I use the original code I write, the MessageBox comes out the long detail including like Row 0 Column 0  Column 1 ....Column 4.
But I want it show  the matrix directly.

Comment: I don't see how the line `double i = Inver.ToString();` Why are you converting it to a `string` when you're assigning it to a `double`?

Answer (score -1):

you can Override ToString method in your inver class and provide your custom formatting. then you just have to call ToString of Inver in Message Box show

```
class Inver
{
...
public override string ToString()
{
    //Build string representation of your inverse matrix
}
}


MessageBox.Show(inver.ToString()); // you can now simply do this
```